# Adjusting opacity and adding annotation and text to matplotlib figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to create some publication quality figures. I want to add text and annotate my points as in my attempt below. I have an issue with my actual figures in .eps format. When I zoom in, the plot points are still visible despite "s = 0.00001" and the opacity of the line appears to change from part to part, looks choppy and not as stylish as I would like it to be. The line also overlaps wit hthe text and points, sometimes it's too messy and hard to read. Any other ideas to breathe some style, and color into my figures would be appreciated as well.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats

x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
y = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
n = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E' , 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I']


slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(x,y)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.scatter(x, y, marker='o', color = 'k', s = 0.00001)
for i, txt in enumerate(n):
    ax.annotate(txt, (x[i],y[i]))
predict_y = [(intercept + (slope * x)) for x in x]
plt.plot(x, predict_y,'k-', alpha=0.4, LineWidth=0.3)
plt.xlabel('Number 1')
plt.ylabel('Number 2')
plt.figtext(.73, .84, u"R²: %0.2f " % r_value**2)
plt.figtext(.73, .79, u"P-value: %0.3f " % p_value)
plt.savefig('test.eps', format = 'eps', dpi=1000)
plt.show()
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What does the plot look like (best add a picture) and what do you not like about it? And most importantly: How would you like to have it instead?

Comment: Accept answers when they are correct if you want next answers. Give something to community, then community gives something to you.

Answer (score 1):

It's wired, if you don't want points to show, why bother using `scatter()`? The plot generated in my computer proves fine, and opacity are not supposed to change according to your code, if it does, I doubt if you screen is clean... And to deal with overlaps, I suggest move the texts a little bit.

I made several changes, trying to make it looks better and add some colors(but I'm not sure if that's the 'stylish' you mean):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats
import numpy.random as npran

x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
y = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
n = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E' , 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I']
col = ['r', 'g', 'b', 'c', 'm', 'y', 'k']

slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(x,y)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.scatter(x, y, marker='o', color = 'k', s = 1) #make points more obvious
for i, txt in enumerate(n):
    #shift texts little
    ax.annotate(txt, (x[i]-0.2, y[i]+0.3), fontsize = 15, \
        color = [npran.rand() for i in range(3)])#make it colorfull?
    #or use color = npran.choice(col)
predict_y = [(intercept + (slope * x)) for x in x]
plt.plot(x, predict_y, 'k-', alpha=0.3, linewidth=0.75) #wider line
plt.xlabel('Number 1', fontsize = 20) #Larger font 
plt.ylabel('Number 2', fontsize = 20)
plt.grid(color = 'r') #add grids
# make the texts together, and move it to right-down
plt.figtext(.65, .15, "$R^2: {:.2f}$\n$P-value: {:.3f}$".format(r_value**2, p_value), \
    bbox={'facecolor':'red', 'alpha':0, 'pad':10}, fontsize = 15)
#you can change to have the boundry box visible
#like 'bbox={'facecolor':'white', 'alpha':1, 'pad':10}'
plt.show()
```

[image: SamplePic]